# Função FWRITE não está gravando em formato binário em linguagem C

Tags: c, arquivo, caracteres

Não estou conseguindo gravar dados em binário em um arquivo utilizando a linguagem C. Mesmo usando 'wb' a saída do arquivo são caracteres.
Como posso proceder?
Eis aqui parte do meu código:

```
void cadastrar(void)
{
     if((fp=fopen("Jogos.dat", "wb"))==NULL)
     {
        printf("\nO arquivo nao pode ser aberto!\n");
        getch();
        exit(1);
     }
     fseek(fp,0L, SEEK_END);
```

`do
 {
    printf("\n Digite o Nome do Jogo ('FIM' para sair): ");
    gets(reg[quantidade_cadastro].nome_jogo);

    if ((strcmp(reg[quantidade_cadastro].nome_jogo,"fim")!=0)&&(strcmp(reg[quantidade_cadastro].nome_jogo,"FIM")!=0))
    {
        printf("\n Ano de Lancamento: ");
        scanf("%d",&reg[quantidade_cadastro].ano_lancamento);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("\n Genero: ");
        gets(reg[quantidade_cadastro].genero);

        printf("\n Plataforma: ");
        gets(reg[quantidade_cadastro].plataforma);

        reg[0].status='1';

        if(fwrite(&reg, sizeof(struct registro), 1, fp) != 1)
        {
            printf("\nErro de Gravacao :/");
            getch();
        }
        else
        {
            quantidade_cadastro++;
            printf("\n Jogo Gravado no Arquivo!\n\n");
        }
    }
 }while((strcmp(reg[quantidade_cadastro].nome_jogo,"fim")!=0)&&(strcmp(reg[quantidade_cadastro].nome_jogo,"FIM")!=0));
 fclose(fp);}`

Comment: Qual é a definição de `struct registro`?

Comment: Este é o registro:
`struct registro
{
    char nome_jogo[40];
    int ano_lancamento;
    char genero[20];
    char plataforma[20];
    char status;
   } reg[50];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu arquivo tem caracteres pelo seguinte motivo.

Como sua `struct` é composta por 4 campos `char` e um campo `int`, o normal é que os dados possam ser lidos.

O método `fwrite` escreve diretamente os valores de sua `struct` dentro de arquivo, sem fazer conversão de valores como o `printf`.

Os valores usados são os da tabela **ascii**. Supondo que você tenha a seguinte `string` "ABCD", os valores seriam escritos como: **65,66,67,68**. E quando o editor de texto fosse ler esses valores ele exibiria ***ABCD***.

Caso um `int` seja escrito no arquivo, o tamanho do `int` em **64bits** vale **4**, e o valor a ser escrito será 65. O valor escrito no arquivo será **65,0,0,0** ou **A** para o editor de texto. Caso o valore escrito seja **16961**, deverá escrever **AB**.

Se usar o comando `string` (presente no bin/ do gcc) será possível ver os nomes dos métodos, as `strings` e das bibliotecas usadas pelo seu sistema, isso por causa da interpretação da tabela **ascii** quando se lê o arquivo.

Caso queira um arquivo com valores ilegíveis (sem caracteres **A-Za-z-0-9**), você deve armazenas valores que fujam o máximo possível dos caracteres literários e numéricos.

Comment: consegui compreender agora. Eu estava pensando que os caracteres seriam substituídos por símbolos assim como é possível notar em alguns arquivos binários já que não tinha conhecimento prévio sobre ASCII. Muito obrigado pela explicação!

Answer (score 0):

O conteúdo dos objectos de tipo `struct registro` é basicamente só texto. Não admira que o conteúdo do ficheiro sejam caracteres.

Verifica a parte do `ano_lancamento` no ficheiro "Jogos.dat".

Como gostarias que o registo seguinte fosse apresentado "em binário"?

```
strcpy(reg[0].nome_jogo, "jogo um");
reg[0].ano_lancamento = 2014;
strcpy(reg[0].genero, "sorte");
strcpy(reg[0].plataforma, "papel e lápis");
```

A diferença entre um ficheiro de texto ou binário prende-se basicamente no tratamento de `"\n"`. Um ficheiro binário não faz tratamento desse caracter, um ficheiro de texto pode converter em `"\r\n"`. Para mais detalhes lê as [secções 7,21,2 e 7.21.3 do Standard C11 (em inglês)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.2).

Comment: Você quer dizer que só é possível gravar em binário se os objetos forem convertidos para inteiro?
No arquivo(ficheiro) "Jogos.dat" apenas o ano de lançamento foi gravado em binário.

Não entendi muito bem a diferença do seu código para o meu. Poderia explicar?

Comment: Ao gravar o caracter `'A'` num ficheiro (binário) o que lá fica é o valor 65 (em computadores baseados em ASCII). Esse valor quando interpretado como caracter é apresentado com "A". Ou seja: não há diferença entre caracter texto e caracter binário.

Comment: Então se não há diferença, qual seria o motivo de o arquivo gravar caracteres?

Comment: A diferença entre um ficheiro de texto ou binário prende-se basicamente no tratamento de "'\n'". Um ficheiro binário não faz tratamento desse caracter, um ficheiro de texto pode converter em `"\r\n"`. Para mais detalhes lê as [secções 7,21,2 e 7.21.3 do Standard C11 (em inglês)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.2).

Comment: @pmg: o que está nos seus comentários deveria estar na resposta - essa que é a duvida dele, e o que é importante documentar aqui.  Será que você pode edita-la e passar essas informações pra resposta?